# CakePHP is linking models locally, but not on hosted copy?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have employees who have one employer. In my employees table I have a field called employer_id. A report using this information is working on my local development setup, but not on my web hosting. I can't figure out what might be causing it not to.

When I try to pull up a list of all the employees I get the following error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Employer.last_name' in 'where clause'
>
> SQL Query: SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`employer_id`,
>   `Employee`.`first_name`, `Employee`.`last_name`, `Employee`.`email`,
>   `Employee`.`webinar_id`, `Employee`.`questions`,
>   `Employee`.`correct_answers`, `Employee`.`required_to_pass`,
>   `Employee`.`status`, `Employee`.`role`, `Employee`.`sport`,
>   `Employee`.`program`, `Employee`.`created`, `Employee`.`modified` FROM
>   `sportrisk_wp`.`employees` AS `Employee` WHERE
>   ((`Employee`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '') AND (`Employer`.`last_name` NOT
>   LIKE '')) AND `contain` = '1' ORDER BY `Employee`.`created` DESC LIMIT
>   50

On my local copy when I change `debug` to 2 I see the following in the SQL log (it's joining the Employer):

> SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`employer_id`,
>   `Employee`.`first_name`, `Employee`.`last_name`, `Employee`.`email`,
>   `Employee`.`webinar_id`, `Employee`.`questions`,
>   `Employee`.`correct_answers`, `Employee`.`required_to_pass`,
>   `Employee`.`status`, `Employee`.`role`, `Employee`.`sport`,
>   `Employee`.`program`, `Employee`.`created`, `Employee`.`modified`,
>   `Employer`.`id`, `Employer`.`employer_id`, `Employer`.`company`,
>   `Employer`.`first_name`, `Employer`.`last_name`, `Employer`.`phone`,
>   `Employer`.`email`, `Employer`.`username`, `Employer`.`password`,
>   `Employer`.`usercode`, `Employer`.`subscriber`, `Employer`.`active`,
>   `Employer`.`admin`, `Employer`.`created`, `Employer`.`modified`,
>   `Employer`.`status` FROM `local`.`employees` AS `Employee` LEFT JOIN
>   `local`.`users` AS `Employer` ON (`Employee`.`employer_id` =
>   `Employer`.`id`) WHERE ((`Employee`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '') AND
>   (`Employer`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '')) ORDER BY `Employee`.`created`
>   DESC LIMIT 50

I believe this is all the relevant code.

UsersController

```
// inside a larger function

// Load Employee Model
$this->loadModel('Employee');

// Base conditions - to hide some old records which do not contain name information.
$conditions = array(
        "Employee.last_name NOT LIKE" => '',
        "Employer.last_name NOT LIKE" => ''
    );

// Find records & paginate
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 50,
    'conditions' => array(
        "AND" => $conditions
    ),
    'order' => array('Employee.created DESC')
);

$employees = $this->paginate('Employee');
?>
```

Employee Model

```
<?php
class Employee extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Employee';
    var $recursive = 1;
    var $belongsTo = array (
        'Employer' => array (
            'className' => 'Employer',
            'foreignKey' => 'employer_id',
            'order' => 'Employee.last_name ASC'
        )
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    var $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'first_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'usercode' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Employer Model

```
<?php
class Employer extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Employer';
    var $recursive = -1;
    var $hasOne = 'Supervisor';
    var $hasMany = 'Employee';

    public $useTable = 'users';
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    var $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

I can't figure out why it isn't linking the Employer model in one environment but is on the other. I've done a straight copy of all the files.

SQL Queries

This is the query I get on the hosted site

```
SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`employer_id`, `Employee`.`first_name`, `Employee`.`last_name`, `Employee`.`email`, `Employee`.`webinar_id`, `Employee`.`questions`, `Employee`.`correct_answers`, `Employee`.`required_to_pass`, `Employee`.`status`, `Employee`.`role`, `Employee`.`sport`, `Employee`.`program`, `Employee`.`created`, `Employee`.`modified` FROM `sportrisk_wp`.`employees` AS `Employee` WHERE ((`Employee`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '') AND (`Employer`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '')) ORDER BY `Employee`.`created` DESC LIMIT 50
```

This is what I get on my local site (and what I'm looking for)

```
SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`employer_id`, `Employee`.`first_name`, `Employee`.`last_name`, `Employee`.`email`, `Employee`.`webinar_id`, `Employee`.`questions`, `Employee`.`correct_answers`, `Employee`.`required_to_pass`, `Employee`.`status`, `Employee`.`role`, `Employee`.`sport`, `Employee`.`program`, `Employee`.`created`, `Employee`.`modified`, `Employer`.`id`, `Employer`.`employer_id`, `Employer`.`company`, `Employer`.`first_name`, `Employer`.`last_name`, `Employer`.`phone`, `Employer`.`email`, `Employer`.`username`, `Employer`.`password`, `Employer`.`usercode`, `Employer`.`subscriber`, `Employer`.`active`, `Employer`.`admin`, `Employer`.`created`, `Employer`.`modified`, `Employer`.`status` FROM `local`.`employees` AS `Employee` LEFT JOIN `local`.`users` AS `Employer` ON (`Employee`.`employer_id` = `Employer`.`id`) WHERE ((`Employee`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '') AND (`Employer`.`last_name` NOT LIKE '')) ORDER BY `Employee`.`created` DESC LIMIT 50
```

END RESULT
In the end (after a chat with Ved) my paginate array ended up being this, and my report loads.

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'contain' => array('Employer'),
            'limit' => 50,
            'conditions' => array(
                "AND" => $conditions
            ),
            'joins' => array( array( 'alias' => 'Employer', 'table' => 'users', 'type' => 'LEFT', 'conditions' => 'Employer.id = Employee.employer_id' ) ),
            'fields' => array('Employee.first_name', 'Employee.last_name', 'Employee.email', 'Employee.webinar_id', 'Employee.questions', 'Employee.correct_answers', 'Employee.required_to_pass', 'Employee.status', 'Employee.role', 'Employee.sport', 'Employee.program', 'Employee.created', 'Employer.id', 'Employer.employer_id', 'Employer.company', 'Employer.first_name', 'Employer.last_name', 'Employer.email', 'Employer.active'),
            'order' => array('Employee.created DESC')
        );
```

Comment: "I've done a straight copy of all the files." - Use git or something similar to verify that both copies are on the same commit id and you don't have changed files. I doubt that the associations magically stop working on another server.

Comment: I've used a diff tool (Kaleidoscope) to verify that the folders are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have forget to load associated data, use contain

```
// Find records & paginate
$this->paginate = array(
    'contain' => array('Employer'),
    'fields' => array('Employer.id'), // add more fields
    'limit' => 50,
    'conditions' => array(
        "AND" => $conditions
    ),
    'joins' => array( array( 'alias' => 'Employer', 'table' => 'users', 'type' 
    => 'LEFT', 'conditions' => 'Employer.id = Employee.employer_id' ) ),
    'order' => array('Employee.created DESC')
);
```

Comment: I just tried adding that. Didn't fix it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: can you provide query generated after adding contain in paginate.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same query as in the block quote at the top of my initial post. There is no left join as there is in my local version. The tables are both there and all the data is the same.

Comment: can you add this 'type' => 'LEFT' in belongs to array and try

Comment: Added, no change. I tried removing the Employer.last_name condition, just to see what would happen. With that gone the purely Employee query works and my report shows up, but with errors for all the fields that should be coming from each employee's employer (as one would expect).

Comment: add this in your paginate array, 'joins' => array(
array(
'alias' => 'Employer',
'table' => 'users',
'type' => 'LEFT',
'conditions' => '`Employer`.`id` = `Widget`.`employer_id`'
)
),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174008/discussion-between-sandbox-wizard-and-ved).